# Calling photoshop droplet using a .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, photoshop

I'm trying to call a photoshop droplet from a .bat file but with no luck. This droplet just opens the image in photoshop, adds a border, and closes it.

Running Windows 7 and Photoshop 6

This is what I already have

for %%a in (*.jpg) 
do (C:\Users\GregT\Desktop\KeylineSaveandClose.exe "%%~a"
)

Any help would be much appreciated

Thankyou

Comment: And what happens when you run your script? And what haapens when you just run a single JPEG through your script?

Comment: The command window opens briefly and shuts itself straight away. I only have the one JPEG in the folder at the moment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's easier to debug scripts from the `Terminal` application than by double-clicking in the GUI. Put any JPEG on your Desktop and call it `test.jog`. Start `Terminal` and type `cd Desktop`. Then try `KeylineSaveandClose  test.jpg`

Comment: If you show a *before* and *after* image, there's probably a much faster way of generating a keyline by the way.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer

for %%a in ("C:\Users\GregT\Desktop\Batch Test*.jpg") do (
start "" /w "C:\Users\GregT\Desktop\Batch Test\keylinesaveandclose.exe" "%%a")

Answer (score 0):

from powershell you have more options:
Start-Process C:\Path\To\Droplet\dropletname.exe -ArgumentList "C:\Path\To\PDF\optimizeme.pdf" -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru